# Not sure how to approach english into latin pig java code

Tags: java, string, if-statement, for-loop

Here's my attempt to write this code but I'm getting lost with a main part.I'm not sure how the loop will know when a new word starts.For now I know only loops and if-else statements.I would really appreciate if you could just push me in a right direction because this problem is way too hard for me.

Rules of pig latin: 
         1)If a word begins with a vowel,add a dash and "way" to the end.
         2)Otherwise,add a dash,move the first letter to the end,and add "ay"

```
/*Enter a line of text: This is a test.

  Input: this is a test.
  Output: his-tay is-way a-way est-tay.
*/



import java.util.Scanner;
public class PigLatin
{
    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
       int count;
       String input;
       char empty = ' ',first;

       Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
       System.out.print("Enter a line of text: ");
       input = keyboard.nextLine();
       System.out.println(); 

       for(count = 0; count < input.length(); count++)
            if(input.charAt(0) != 'a' || input.charAt(0) != 'e' != input.charAt(0) != 'o' != input.charAt(0) != 'i' != input.charAt(0) != 'u')
                System.out.print(input.charAt(count + 1) + "-" + input.charAt(0) + "ay");
            else if(input.charAt(count) == empty) 
                    first = input.charAt(count + 1)
                    if(input.charAt(first) != 'a' || input.charAt(0) != 'e' != input.charAt(0) != 'o' != input.charAt(0) != 'i' != input.charAt(0) != 'u')
                    System.out.print(input.charAt(first + 1) + "-" + input.charAt(first) + "ay");
            else if()
                    System.out.print("-way"); //I'm lost here.
     }
 }
```

Comment: Hint: You should probably start by splitting the line into an array of words, and then work with each word individually. Try using `String[] parts = input.split(" ");`.

Comment: I don't know how to use arrays yet.As far as I know this problem can be solved with for and if-else statements which I'm having trouble with.

Comment: You can detect that a new word starts if there are white spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class PigLatin {

    static final char vowelRegex = "^[aeiouy]"; //Is y a vowel?

    public static void main(String[]args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a line of text: ");
        String input = keyboard.nextLine();
        String[] words = input.split(' ');

        for(int i=0; i<words.length; i++) {
            if(words[i].matches(vowelRegex)) {
                System.out.print(words[i] + "-way ");
            } else {
                System.out.println(words[i].substring(1) + words[i].charAt(0) + "-ay ";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks PlasmaPower but I didn't get to arrays yet.

Comment: @user3003920 Is regex ok?

Comment: Consider a character class instead of the or: `[aeouy]`.

Comment: @aliteralmind Thanks, my ninja regex skills are failing me :/.

Comment: Not a problem. You'll always be a ninja in my heart.